# fine-grained colour gradient legend

Tags: r, gradient, legend

I have a problem when making a colour gradient legend. In my case the data can range from 0 to 1, and the differences between values can be very small, making the legend look more or less unicolour. Is there a way to make the gradient more fine-grained?

```
#dummy data
prob <- c(0.24228,0.24330,0.19590,0.28554,0.18260,0.24626,0.21664,0.21598,0.22754,0.19366,0.36778,0.18854,0.48554,0.21922,0.20212,0.25406,0.18744,0.22476,0.17464,0.20828,0.19084,0.21878,0.17642,0.17190,0.31024,0.30492,0.16838,0.22374,0.20550,0.21550,0.19432,0.22890,0.17526,0.16864,0.33064,0.20454,0.19704,0.30926,0.18156,0.26320,0.18686,0.18234,0.17128,0.19186,0.39960,0.23060,0.26152,0.42696,0.25806,0.16712,0.17568,0.28280,0.19872,0.16790,0.28618,0.31684,0.36114,0.32234,0.23386,0.19820,0.21796,0.22628,0.16930,0.16700,0.16364,0.19562,0.19706,0.20404,0.22368,0.39426,0.23390,0.26944,0.22828,0.17430,0.16262,0.16722,0.16362,0.19150,0.39826,0.32130,0.28422,0.16902,0.19758,0.18310,0.17334,0.17308,0.16654,0.20186,0.26402,0.17904,0.20244,0.23508,0.25188,0.36882,0.18062,0.24956,0.20742,0.17328,0.18414,0.19626,0.19368,0.36542,0.23246,0.19910,0.31924,0.35536,0.31374,0.28556,0.29444,0.19620,0.18296,0.17322,0.33390,0.16920,0.30898,0.41456,0.16678,0.48374,0.24966,0.17130,0.42178,0.20878,0.22610,0.17204,0.19620,0.50638)

# update - fix
prob <- prob[!duplicated(prob)]

my.palette <- rev(rgb(prob[order(prob)], 1-prob[order(prob)], 0, maxColorValue=1))
image(1, prob[order(prob)], t(seq_along(prob)), col=my.palette, axes=FALSE, main="probability")
axis(2)
```

[image]

Comment: Your code gives me "Error in image.default(1, prob[order(prob)], t(seq_along(prob)), col = my.palette,  : 
  increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected" so I think something needs sorting...

Comment: Still not working... same error.

Comment: Again, sorry for the error in the dummy data. The problem was due to duplicates. In the real data, the values have very long (invisible) decimals, but when writing it to file the values got rounded off, making some values identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are plotting your data rather than making a legend.

Anyway.. The problem is the mismatch between your data range and maxColorValue. So, you can set the max...

```
red <- prob[order(prob)]
green <- max(prob)-prob[order(prob)]
my.palette <- rev(rgb(red, green, 0, maxColorValue=max(prob)))
image(1, prob[order(prob)], t(seq_along(prob)), col=my.palette, axes=FALSE, 
      main="probability")
axis(2)
```

..or rescale the data for better color variations.

```
scaledprob <- (prob[order(prob)]- min(prob)) / (max(prob) - min(prob))
my.palette <- rev(rgb(scaledprob, 1-scaledprob, 0, maxColorValue=1))
image(1, prob[order(prob)], t(scaledprob), col=my.palette, axes=FALSE, 
      main="probability")
axis(2)
```